# How to calculate arc start position

Tags: calculus, arc-length

I'm working on an interactive pH spectrum in JavaScript! Here is an image of what I have so far [EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgbTE.png)!

What I want to calculate is the `startPos` and `endPos` (with offset) of each pH level (the text 0,1,2,...)!

At the moment if you look on the image provided I added the levels customly by giving hard values! However I want to provide a formula that would allow my program to calculate this automatically!

FYI I'm working with a half circle and the starting position is 180 and ends at 360 degrees! That's how JavaScript works!

The values I know:

- The center of the circle!
- The degree of each arc (12.9)
- The startPos and endPos of each arc (eg. x:180, y:192.9)

I want to calculate the X Y position of the black dots in the image!

---

UPDATE:
My program works as expected but I'm not sure if the math matches.

```
function draw_preferred_ph(minValue, maxValue){
  //Font Settings
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(1);
  
  //Original value of theta = 12.9
  //FORMULA : input * (theta -1) + 180 + trunc(input)
  var startDeg = minValue*11.9+180+Math.trunc(minValue);
  var endDeg = maxValue*11.9+180+Math.trunc(maxValue);
  
  //Draw arc representing minimum and maximum pH levels!
  squareColor = color(100, 50, 100);
  squareColor.setAlpha(100);
  fill(squareColor);

  //PARAMS: startX,startY, W, H, startDegree, FinishDegree, TYPE:PIE
  arc(0,0,r*2,r*2,startDeg,endDeg,PIE);
  
  ///DRAW LABELS OF MIN AND MAX VALUES 
  noStroke();
  fill(0, 102, 153);

  text("MIN pH:  " + minValue, -340,-320)
  text("MAX pH:  " + maxValue, 160, -320);
}
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQwUU.png)

Comment: This is straightforward trigonometry, which javascript knows.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3hPn8YMAhFk

Answer (score 0):

As Ethan Bolker suggested, this can be done with help of trigonometric functions. Let $\{c_h,c_v\}$ denote be the coordinates of the center and $r$ the radius of the circle. As you need to place $15$ dots, the angular distance between them is $12$, and the position of the $n^{th}$ dot should be $$\{x,y\}=\{c_h+r\cos (180+12 n),c_h+r\sin (180+12 n)\}$$

Comment: I have updated my question. The formula I'm using is the following `FORMULA : input * (theta -1) + 180 + trunc(input)`! Please remember that I'm using `theta-1` I don't know why but it works. And that I working with half a sphere!